# inheritance types in classes chain

Tags: javascript, inheritance

i created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6NsB/2/) to show the problem i'm facing.
I suggest to look at it before going on reading.

Ok, now we're ready.
As you saw there is a class inheritance chain: `LeafDevice` -> `EndDevice` -> `SubNetDevice` -> `NetDevice` -> `Device`.
When i instantiate a new `LeafDevice` the chain is fulfilled (ie it executes in the correct order) but only attributes from `LeafDevice` and `EndDevice` are set (look at the console).
When i run the update method it seems to jump a class every 2... I mean, you see from the output that javascript doesn't seem to run the `EndDevice.update()` and `NetDevice.update()` methods... Only attributes from `Device`, `SubNetDevice` and `LeafDevice` are updated/added (again, look at the console)...
This is driving me crazy as i cannot figure out what i'm doing wrong!!
What i'm trying to do is to instantiate a `LeafDevice` object that follows the inheritance chain i defined so that at the end it has all defined attributes (`myDeviceAttr`, `myNetDeviceAttr`, `mySubNetDeviceAttr`, `myEndDeviceAttr`, `myLeafDeviceAttr`).
Can you give some ideas on what's going on here please?
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you use to call update EndDevice & expecting `update EndDevice` to come up

```
EndDevice.prototype.update.call(this, pDevice);
```

But here

```
EndDevice.prototype = new SubNetDevice;
```

You clearly assign an object of SubNetDevice as EndDevice's prototype

So, EndDevice.prototype.update is equivalent to

```
var a = new SubNetDevice();
a.update()
```

Hence, No way You can see `update EndDevice` in your log

The reason is the same for Net Device too.

Try http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

The extend Function in the link above should solve ur problem

To Fix the above mentioned fiddle, in LeafDevice change

```
EndDevice.prototype.update.call(this, pDevice);
```

To

```
LeafDevice.prototype.update.call(this, pDevice);
```

This change is required because, you are expected to call LeafDevice's -> EndDevice's -> Update method which is available @ `LeafDevice.prototype.update` but not here `EndDevice.prototype` which is EndDevice's -> SubNetDevice's -> Update method

The same applies for all your classes

Also You had missed `.call` in

```
SubNetDevice(this, pDevice);
```

This should fix your properties issue

http://jsfiddle.net/v6NsB/8/ this is your updated fiddle

Comment: I think that script is not very good as in my tests it doesn't make possible to use methods with one or more parameters. If you have proofs of the contrary please show a working example and i will use it. Anyway i'd be glad not to use this kind of script and use natural oop behaviour of javascript (i know it can be made)! I'm not going to accept this an an answer as it doesn't show clearly how to solve the problem (until you elaborate a bit, sorry)

Comment: @andreapier I have fixed your script in the fiddle, have a look at it. I'm not getting what are you really trying to do. Your question lacks proper explanation. Yesterday I answered "This is driving me crazy as i cannot figure out what i'm doing wrong" Now I have updated your script to work as you expected

Comment: Well, now the update method works as expected but the constructor doesn't... if you look deeper you can see that the LeafDevice object has only myEndDeviceAttr and myLeafDeviceAttr... it doesn't have mySubNetDeviceAttr, myNetDeviceAttr and myDeviceAttr. @Tamil

Comment: @andreapier It is fixed. In your script you had missed here `SubNetDevice(this, pDevice);` You had missed `.call`  check this http://jsfiddle.net/v6NsB/7/

Comment: @andreapier this is the final update fiddle ignore the previous http://jsfiddle.net/v6NsB/8/

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been very kind!